# What is the easiest way to create a script that runs on the next reboot only?

Tags: linux, bash, reboot, init.d

I am looking to create a script that executes on the next reboot only (not each reboot).

For example, I have script `test.sh`:

```
cd /tmp
touch toto.txt
```

What is the easiest way to execute this script only on the next reboot?

By easiest I mean : minimal number of commands, and independent of the linux OS/Version (if possible).

After several searches I found I can use the `init.d` system. But I think that's not the best way, because my script must run only once.

Answer (score 1):

Add something like

```
LOCKFILE=/var/lock/test_sh_done
if [ ! -f ${LOCKFILE} ]; then
    touch ${LOCKFILE}
    /path/to/test.sh
fi
```

to /etc/rc.local, and make sure that /etc/rc.local has the execute bit set. If you want to run it again at the next reboot, just delete the LOCKFILE.

Comment: Hmmm I see..but one question, the rc.local is called each multiuser runlevel isn't it ? So the script is executed when the linux OS finished booting ? (all services availables)